# Tool for Merging Multiple .SQL Files

Tags: mysql, sql, unix

Right now we have a ~5000 line .sql file consisting of tables, functions, triggers and other definition/declarations. The idea is to split this into multiple sql files in order to restrain from having the same file being edited by multiple people at the same time. Then, right before build time the files will be merged back into one temporarily file where our scripts will then import and create the database.

My initial thoughts were to just create a bash script and concatenate the files in the appropriate order to rebuild the ~5000 line .sql file that can then be imported. I was curious if there was some type of mysql, psql or other linux specific command that was capable of doing this in a much more elegant and cleaner way?

Comment: Are you using a version control tool? Its not an answer to your question, but using git or mercurial would solve the problem, it seems.

Comment: As I understand it, @Pelshoff suggests you use GIT or Mercurial (or even SVN) to edit a 5000 line .SQL file concurrently.  That would actually work, as those tools can detect and merge changes to parts of a file.  It might be preferable to 500+ .SQL files.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't fully explaining myself. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but we do already have a system to track versions. I would rather not go into great detail but lets just say that the only option is to split the file into 5-10 smaller .sql files which still leaves me wondering if there is a more elegant solution then a bash script.

Comment: Would you also suggest that all of your Java/C++/whatever code all be put into one big file? I think that's a mistake as it isn't very difficult to run many files in sequence or to merge them.

Comment: But that is different with C++/C/whatever because I can split those files and I (emphasis on I) actually know how to compile those split files to work properly. The difference here is that I know how to spli the SQL files (which is pretty obvious) but I do not know how to properly compile them to work properly (aside from cheating and using a bash script to temporarily compile them back into one large file).

Comment: `make` is the right tool for putting those files together in the right order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to get cleaner than `cat *.sql`, IMHO.  Just make sure you name the files so that a shell glob will expand to the correct inclusion order.  i.e., if you have `make-tables.sql` and `load-tables.sql` then you can't use a simple `*` because that will put `load-` before `make-`.

Putting a number prefix in front of each file may remind you of old-school BASIC line numbers, but it works.

```
01-init.sql
10-create-tables.sql
15-create-indexes.sql
20-create-functions.sql
25-create-triggers.sql
75-load-data.sql
99-run-reports.sql
```

or something like that.